# Problema: Unknown column 'X' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando hacer altas de un psicologo mediante una pagina web y que eso vaya a la base de datos. Ya probe varios codes, pero ninguno me funciono. Estoy usando el codigo igual al de mi amigo (adaptado a mi base de datos) y a mi no me funciona. Necesito una respuesta lo antes posible. El lunes entrego esta base.

BASE DE DATOS:

```
-- Table structure for table `psicologo`
--

CREATE TABLE `psicologo` (
  `IdPsico` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id Psicólogo ',
  `Nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Apellido` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Direc` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Dirección ',
  `DNI` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Tel` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Teléfono '
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `psicologo`
--

INSERT INTO `psicologo` (`IdPsico`, `Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Direc`, `DNI`, `Tel`) VALUES
(1, 'Omar', 'Juarez', 'Avellaneda 1240', '48018943', '+52 9 11 1098-4567'),
(2, 'Kenny', 'Stompfield', 'Conneticut 124', '348018943', '+1 9 11 1093-4167'),
(3, 'Juan Maria', 'Gonzales Carmil', 'Uruguay 1234', '42026917', '+54 9 11 2288-1923');

-- --------------------------------------------------------



--
-- Indexes for table `psicologo`
--
ALTER TABLE `psicologo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`IdPsico`),
  ADD KEY `IdPsico` (`IdPsico`);

--

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `psicologo`
--
ALTER TABLE `psicologo`
  MODIFY `IdPsico` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id Psicólogo ', AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Esa es la parte de psicologos en la base de datos, la cual estoy usando para la pagina y el code que estoy usando para hacer las altas es el siguiente

CODE:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include("conexion.php")
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  Nuevo Psicologo
    <br>
  Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre" required ><br>
  Apellido:<input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese apellido" required ><br>
  Dirección:<input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese dirección" required ><br>
  DNI:<input type="text" name="dni" placeholder="Ingrese DNI" required ><br>
  Teléfono:<input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Ingrese teléfono" required ><br>
  <input type="submit" name="enviar">

<?php
 if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
   $Nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
   $Apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
   $Direc=$_POST["direccion"];
   $DNI=$_POST["dni"];
   $Tel=$_POST["telefono"];

   $sql= "INSERT INTO `psicologo`(`Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Direc`, `DNI`, `Tel`) VALUES (`$Nombre`,`$Apellido`,`$Direc`,`$DNI`,`$Tel`) ";
   $resp=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql ) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));}
 ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="menu" value="npsico">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el code que estoy usando.
AYUDA, POR FAVOR

Comment: Consejo: No solicites ayuda **urgente** porque pueden cerrarte la pregunta por ello. En [esta página](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152/263200) lo explican.

Comment: Por otra parte, prueba quitando las comillas inversas en los VALUES y pon comillas simples normales. Es decir, pon esto: `('$Nombre','$Apellido','$Direc','$DNI','$Tel')` a ver si con eso ya lo arreglas.  Las comillas inversas (o acentos graves) solo se usan en el nombre de los campos, no en los valores.  Y creo que tampoco está bien que lo uses en el nombre de la tabla `psicologo`, ponlo sin allí.

Comment: Buenas! He revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos.